# Loading a picture off the UI thread?

Tags: objective-c

How could I load a picture from a resource on a background thread?

I am currently doing this and it slows things quite a bit on my UI:

```
image = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:imageName];
```

I would rather it load it on a background thread.

Comment: can't you just use GCD and wrap those lines in there?

Comment: I am not very familiar with iOS and just learning.  Could you give an example?

Comment: well what I meant was what jano said, alternatively you can use performSelectorInBackground ( NSObject method )

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
dispatch_queue_t backgroundQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
dispatch_queue_t mainQueue = dispatch_get_main_queue();
dispatch_async(backgroundQueue,^{
  // background process
  image = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:imageName];
  dispatch_async(mainQueue,^{
    // always update GUI from the main thread
    // uiimageview.image = image.... etc
 });
});
```

Comment: I'm doing this, but i'm calling 5 dataWithContentsOfFile sequentially to get five 5MB JPGs from disk, it's still block the UI. I've also tried by splitting in 5 queues as your solution, and by usig the same logic but with NSOperationQueue, but both are still blocking the UI. There are a plenty of threads on this but i can't find a good solution. Do you know any doc/ref for the asynchronous loading of local assets/files?

Answer (score 3):

you can use a `CGDataProvider` to open a `CGImage`.

for example, you can use `CGImageCreateWithPNGDataProvider`, and the data provider would refer to a `CFURL`. you can use a similar approach for `CFData` representations.

then you can use the `CGImage` or hop back to the main thread and create a `UIImage` representation.

finally, you can just load the `CFData` or `NSData` from a secondary thread, then hop back to the main thread to do something with it.

it may also be worth noting that `UIImage` is an immutable type, and uses a cache in some cases. if you are loading the same representation multiple times, ensure you are not disabling that optimization.